# How to do Javascript event driven mouse logging?

Tags: javascript, events, logging, mouse

I have seen some snippets to get the mouse position and read a bit about jquery-one. Would someone please make or show me an example of detecting the position of the mouse whenever it is moved and saving the sequence of the coordinates and clicks with click coordinates to an array (or delimited string variable might be better) as it runs and then when the user navigates away from the page (or clicks a link on the page) it will POST the event log to a php file? I can write the php part.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect mouse movement with `window.onmousemove`. The coordinates are accumulated in `xList` and `yList`, and when the window unloads the `unload()` function is called. From there you can do whatever you want with the lists, but be warned, they will get very long very fast!

```
window.onmousemove = mouseMoved;
window.onunload = unload;

var xList = [];
var yList = [];

function mouseMoved(evt){
    evt = evt || window.event; //compatibility with IE and other browsers
    xList.push(evt.clientX);
    yList.push(evt.clientY);
}

function unload(){
    //do something with xList and yList
    alert("unloading");
}
```

See example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYZ55/). It doesn't show the unload functionality, but it displays the current coordinates in a `div`.